# How to identify different devices with same user using firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to identify each device a single user uses, like if a user called John uses a windows laptop to signin. I want to know that he is signed in using windows. If he did using android, I want to know that as well.

If that is not feasible is there any other possible way I can Identify a device with some static address?

I want this data either by Firebase or GCP Services, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to identify each separate install of the app, you'll typically want to look into Instance ID ([Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/InstanceID), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.installations.Installations)). This gives a unique ID for each instance/installation of the app, and is used by Firebase itself with Cloud Messaging (to identify the specific app instance to send a message to), by Crashlytics (to record on what device crashes happen), and *can* be used in Analytics (to identify the device). By combining the Instance ID with the Firebase Authentication UID, you can identify a user and their devices.